# VB and Angular working toghether

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, vb.net

I'm working on a project where I'm making a file editor.
the frontend I would love to have in angular.

So i've setup my angular project to be loaded when going to the webform aspx page.

but now I need to load in the document. This happens via a library and some vb code (for authentication and so on). And I can see that I need to pass data between the javascript and the VB side a couple of times (like when the users presses save and so on).

right now the vb part just builds a hughe html string and does:

```
content.Binary = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(html)
Context.Response.BinaryWrite(content.Binary)
Context.Response.Flush()
Context.Response.End()
```

But I would think there is more efficient way to send data between the two.

I've found this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35373/VB-NET-C-and-JavaScript-communication but that is using a Webbrowser, and that doesn't seem to work on the `System.Web.UI.Page`

Comment: How big are the documents?

Comment: They are mostly files less then 50mb

Comment: You want to open 50MB files in an editor on a web page??

Comment: Basicly (the file size increases fast when you start embedding images :) )

Comment: What is the file type then, if you can embed images?  I assumed it was html, from the code example.

Comment: it's a custom file type, but it exists of basic html

Comment: You shouldn't be embedding images in html in that case.  You should upload images separately and link them as normal with image tags in the html.  If you need to create a self-contained version, with all the images embedded, then treat that as a separate part of the process.  The only way you can edit and save data is to pass it to and from the browser so other than doing that I don't see what other option you have.

Comment: I can't change how the files are saved / process images. But i'm trying now to return the HTML via a rest api

Comment: If you can't change the file format then you're stuck with what you have.  The idea of editing files over the internet that are potentially around 50MB is just plain wrong.  Sorry, but I don't see a solution to this particular problem unless you can parse the existing data to remove embedded images.